# The html5 download attribute is not working in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

The download is not downloading the images, instead it just redirects to another page. I tried this in new chrome, edge and in my mobile also but this not working, it is just redirecting to another page. I am using the links from the unsplash.com.

When the user clicks on the download icon, the image must be downloaded, how to achieve this?

Here is my code,

```
import React from "react";

const CardImage = ({ img, name, id }) => {
  return (
    <figure className="cardImg">
      <img src={img} alt="" />
      <span className="name">{name}</span>
      <div className="overlay"></div>
      <div className="cardImg__buttons">
        <a href={img} className="download" download target="_blank">
          <i className="fas fa-download"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="#" className="delete">
          <i className="fas fa-trash"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </figure>
  );
};

export default CardImage;
```

Comment: Where are hosted the images?

Comment: it may be due to the link. check unsplash documentation about the same

Answer (score -1):

You can simply give the link of image with extension. Something like this:

```
//Download as image.png

 <a download="image.png" target="_blank" href="http://example.org/assets/avatar.png">
          <i className="fas fa-download"></i>
 </a>
```

Comment: But it is not working. I already tried this, but it doesn't work. I am using links from Unsplash

Comment: @SumukhaKb Did you give value to download attribute like download='filename' ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it doesn't work. Is it because of Unsplash link?

Comment: No, can you host your code on codesandbox? I will take a look

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-nightingale-zee0e?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Will you be fetching images from api? Or some pre defined images?

Comment: I fetch images from an API